# Android IAP v3 - Can buy managed item several times

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am implementing an IAP scheme for android, and I have come acrossed something really strange. I have started from the TriviaDrive sample that Google offers, I have changed the key to mine, I have signed it with the developer key, uploaded it to Developer Console, created the IAP items (managed) and activated them. The app is in draft mode.

The situation is that I can buy one item with a test account, it looks to be consumed and I received an email from Google saying that I have made a purchase. So far so good. But unfortunately, if I try again to buy the item, the same process happens again, email from Google included.

Does anybody have a clue of why this could be happening? I've check dozens of time that the products are managed, that my key is correct and they are right...I'm quite lost now.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I had a line in the code in which I was consuming the item, thus making it elegible to be purchased again. It turns out that a managed product can be consumable after all.

Comment: can you please share some code example or more description on it?